# Cardano serialization lib for PHP

Tags: cardano-serialization-lib

I'm trying to authenticate a user against a (or any) PHP platform (Drupal, Symfony, Laravel,..) by having the user connect with their wallet (Eternl, Nami, ...).

As far as I understand, the following things need to happen:

- Backend provides a nonce or unique string to the client
- Client signs a message containing the string with their wallet
- Client sends the signature back to the server
- Server deserializes the signature and checks if the signature is valid
- Server issues a JWT token (or other means of authentication), the client can use in later requests

There is a good example of how to do this using NodeJs and javascript (https://github.com/pyropy/web3-cardano-token). However, I can't seem to find anything that would enable me to do the same using PHP.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks alot!

**Edit**: Taking matters into my own hands. Currently porting https://github.com/StricaHQ/cip08 to a php library. Halfway there. Will report back when I have it in a public repo.

Comment: DId you ever get round to this?